# Transfer an executable from a server which doesn't allow scp

Tags: security, ubuntu, scp

I have an ELF executable on a server which doesn't allow scp transfers. It also doesn't allow outbound connections of any type. I don't have root access to it. Is there a way to copy this executable from the server? Maybe there is a way to dump object code to stdout, copy it and convert back to an executable on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, run `base64 thefile`. Then copy the output it produces. On your computer, run `base64 -d > thefile`, paste the output, then hit Ctrl+D.